# Has any US President served in a government position with a foreign nation before or after their presidency?

Tags: united-states, political-history, president

Has a person elected to the US Presidency ever held a government position in a nation besides the United States?

I think any government-related role would be an interesting answer.  I think the focus here is the role acts as a representative of the country, or to officially influence sovereign matters.

I do not think the role must have been voted by the people of that nation.

Comment: I thought to look at whether anyone who had served the Confederate states ended up president. Unsurprisingly, no. Sounds like the eventual answer will be no though, due to the [Natural-born-citizen clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-born-citizen_clause) making it unlikely. I assume military roles over foreign troops (Eisenhower for example) and US military governance of subdued countries would not count.

Comment: Benjamin Franklin?

Comment: I think I will answer Eisenhower, but I'm pretty sure there were more. In the US controlled far east for example. Edit: good there's another answer with that in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most obvious examples would be three members of the Founding Fathers who served in roles for the British government.

- George Washington served as both a [member](http://www.mountvernon.org/educational-resources/encyclopedia/burgesses) of the [Virginia House of Burgesses](http://encyclopediavirginia.org/House_of_Burgesses) which dealt directly with the royal appointed Governor of Virginia, and as a [member of the British army](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/british-soldier-george-washington-experiences-combat-for-first-time).
- John Adams was briefly a member of the [Massachusetts assembly](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/generic/VP_John_Adams.htm) after the [Boston Massacre](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/the-boston-massacre).
- Thomas Jefferson was briefly a [member](http://www2.vcdh.virginia.edu/lewisandclark/biddle/biographies_html/jefferson.html) of the Virginia House of Burgesses.

After Washington, and Jefferson, it appears only two men who would become president served in any sort of meaningful capacity for a "foreign" government.

- William Taft served another nation as [the Governor-General of the Philippines](http://www.sheppardsoftware.com/History/presidents/Presidents_27_Taft.htm), although he did so at the behest of the United States since it was a US colony at the time. For example, he [negotiated on the behalf of the Philippines with the Roman Catholic Church](http://millercenter.org/academic/americanpresident/taft/essays/biography/2) over the purchase of Philippine lands.
- Herbert Hoover was in charge of a large relief effort, the [Commission for Relief in Belgium](http://www.baef.be/documents/about-us/history/the-commission-for-relief-in-belgium-1914-.xml?lang=en), during WWI that was international in nature. Technically, the commission was not a part of a government, but [it did negotiate with foreign governments, and conduct diplomacy with the warring powers](http://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/1989/spring/hoover-belgium.html). After WWI he was [in charge of](http://millercenter.org/president/hoover/essays/biography/2) the [Supreme Economic Council](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/574865/Supreme-Economic-Council) which was run by the five victorious great powers from WWI.

Comment: Don't forget John Adams, who was engaged to defend the British soldiers who perpetrated the [Boston Massacre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams#Boston_Massacre)

Comment: Please edit Filipine to Philippine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

President John Tyler served for the Confederacy after being president. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tyler).  The 14th amendment specifically prohibits former Confederates from serving certain offices 
(Specifically:

> (Section 3) prohibits the election or appointment to any federal or
>   state office of any person who had held any of certain offices and
>   then engaged in insurrection, rebellion or treason. However, a
>   two-thirds vote by each House of the Congress can override this
>   limitation. 
>   )
>   (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)

Answer (score 3):

Eisenhower perhaps qualifies, who was [Military Governor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_D._Eisenhower#Military_Governor_in_Germany_and_Army_Chief_of_Staff) of  the U.S. Occupation Zone in Germany from the end of WW2 up to November 1945. He was responsible for the Joint Chiefs of Staff's directive [1067](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCS_1067#JCS_1067), the blueprint for rebuilding Germany after the war. He was responsible for distribution of food, medicine, dealing with the concentration camps and providing civil order/justice.

Comment: I'd say no (but good try). He wouldn't have been given that position if he hadn't been a US general, and I doubt there was any confusion about whose interests he was there to represent. McArthur was in a pretty much identical postion wrt Japan after their surrender.

Comment: Was Ike paid by the Germans or the US during that period? That'd make a big difference in whether he was working for a foreign government or not (did Germany even have an actual government during that period yet that could have employed him? )

Comment: He was still in the army so I imagine the US. Counting US control of foreign countries is sketchy, but not hugely more than counting British colonial administration as "foreign". I don't think there are any fantastic examples.